# jQuery put into an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/Cfa6c/8/

Basically what I need to do is get the text value of the elements `.email_module` and put them into an array. So if there was

```
<span class = "email_module">
example@example.com
</span>

<span class = "email_module">
somebody@somebody.com
</span>
```

the variables `emails` would be `example@example.com,somebody@somebody.com`.

I have tried this code

```
$('.email_module').map(function () { return $(this).text(); });
```

but it doesn't work, could anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close using `$.map` but forgot to convert map result (which is jquery collection) to the array with `.get()` method:

```
var emails = $('.email_module').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

See this updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/Cfa6c/11/

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`.makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)

```
$.makeArray( $(".email_module").text().trim());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EG8Ee/10/)

---

i think this should suffice

```
$(".email_module").text();
```

here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EG8Ee/6/)

---

though the above code will produce a string, for the array you can do

```
var arr=[];
$(".email_module").each(function(i,j){    
arr.push($(j).text().trim());
});

console.log(arr);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EG8Ee/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var emails = $('.email_module').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4zh5a/

Answer (score -1):

```
var emailList = [];

var i = 0;

$('.email_module').each(function() {

emailList[i] = $(this).text();
i++;

});
```

Comment: -1 not necessary when jQuery has this functionality built in.

Comment: Also, this code causes an error since you didn't define `emailList` to be an array.